# Sql query to get minimum date and other detail from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 4 tables with date column and status column.I want to compare date range from 1st table with rest of tables and get min date and status for table.

I know i can get min date by using CTE and union all tables and applying `MIN()` function to get min date but i want to get minimum date and status for date.

Eg : 1st table output

```
personCount Running StatusId MinStartTime               MinEndTime
3           94      1        2014-02-21 05:40:38.723    2014-02-21 07:14:36.320
4           131     1        2014-02-21 07:14:36.320    2014-02-21 10:05:26.690
```

2nd table output :

```
personCount Running StatusId MinStartTime               MinEndTime
3           104     2        2014-02-21 06:26:44.870    2014-02-21 08:10:21.830
```

3rd Table output :

```
personCount Running StatusId MinStartTime               MinEndTime
3           8       4        2014-02-21 06:18:44.203    2014-02-21 06:26:44.857
1           4       4        2014-02-21 12:38:42.857    2014-02-21 12:42:07.577
```

4th Table output:

```
personCount Running StatusId MinStartTime               MinEndTime
5           7       8        2014-02-21 10:04:04.367    2014-02-21 10:11:38.983
4           9       8        2014-02-21 10:11:38.983    2014-02-21 10:20:27.063
```

So i want to Get Minimum of MinStartTime and statusId for that time  from table 2nd,3rd and 4th table if that dates comes between 1st table start and endtime.

Eg : For 1st row of 1st table MinStartTime is `2014-02-21 05:40:38.723` and MinEndtime is :`2014-02-21 07:14:36.320`

So i want to query to 2nd,3rd and 4th table where MinstartTime of 2nd,3rd and 4th table should comes between 1st table start and endtime. and it will return minstarttime and status for that time.

So for 1st row of first table,i should get 3rd table starttime and status, As its the minimum time.

Same for 2nd row of 1st table ,i should get 4th table first row.

How do i get this result.

Comment: What would be the desired output for your sample data?

Comment: I have updated the question with desired output.

Comment: How would you get the first row of table4 for the second row in table1, since it's not between the first table's start and end time?

Comment: sorry my mistake... now chk

Answer (score 0):

The query will be somewhat limited sue to the lack of a primary key, but something like this should do it;

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t1.MinStartTime t1ms, t2.MinStartTime t2ms, t2.StatusId,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.MinStartTime ORDER BY t2.MinStartTime) rn
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table3 UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM table4) t2
    ON t2.MinStartTime BETWEEN t1.MinStartTime AND t1.MinEndTime
)
SELECT t2ms MinStartTime, StatusId FROM cte WHERE rn=1;
```

A primary key on the tables would make the query better (and most likely more performant), since you could partition by that key instead of Table1's `MinStartTime`. Right now, multiple ranges in Table1 starting at the exact same time will be counted as a single range.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3ec4/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
WITH TAB1 AS (SELECT * FROM TABLE2
             UNION ALL
             SELECT * FROM TABLE3
             UNION ALL
             SELECT * FROM TABLE4),
TAB2 AS
(SELECT * FROM TAB1 WHERE MinStartTime = 
(SELECT MIN(MinStartTime) FROM TAB1))
SELECT TAB2.MinStartTime,TAB2.StatusId FROM 
TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TAB2 ON 
TAB2.MinStartTime BETWEEN T1.MinStartTime AND T1.MinEndTime;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d496f8/4)